# How do I change the look of the Windows form window when developing for Pocket PC in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, pocketpc

I'm developing for Pocket PC in Visual Studio 2003. When I create a Windows form it has the look of a classic XP frame with the 'X' and underline in the right top corner. How do I change the look into the Pocket PC window with an 'Ok' button in the top right corner?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand what you are talking about without a screenshot, but I think you are wanting the ControlBox properties.

Visual Studio 2008 Properties are shown below, as I don't have access to VS2003 anymore.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is how I want the window to look like http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC55514.gif instead of the windows xp look.

Comment: That's what mine look like. It could be that you are using VS2003 and/or and older SDK.